# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' when trying to add a child

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm getting an error when I run my code. The error is;

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'topObstacle1'

I searched about problem but I can not find any solution. I know the row where error occurs. [self addChild:topObstacles[y]] is the source of problem. Here is my code;

```
- (void)createObstacles
{
    // Calculate how many obstacles we need, the less the better
    nbObstacles = ceil(WIDTH(self)/(OBSTACLE_INTERVAL_SPACE));

    CGFloat lastBlockPos = 0;
    bottomObstacles = @[].mutableCopy;
    topObstacles = @[].mutableCopy;

    SKSpriteNode * topObstacle1 = [SKSpriteNode   spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"topObstacle1"];
[topObstacles addObject:topObstacle1];

SKSpriteNode * topObstacle2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"topObstacle2"];
[topObstacles addObject:topObstacle2];

SKSpriteNode * bottomObstacle1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bottomObstacle1"];
[bottomObstacles addObject:bottomObstacle1];

SKSpriteNode * bottomObstacle2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bottomObstacle2"];
[bottomObstacles addObject:bottomObstacle2];


for (int i=0;i<nbObstacles;i++) {

    int y = arc4random() % 2;
    [topObstacles[y] setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];

    [self addChild:topObstacles[y]];

    int z = arc4random() % 2;
    [bottomObstacles[z] setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];

    [self addChild:bottomObstacles[z]];

    }
```

So, what do u think about this?

Comment: You are adding a node to the same parent twice.

Comment: What do u mean exactly, how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pick a random array index in a for loop where the same index (y) can be chosen again randomly, thus adding the same object (say the one at index 1) twice:

```
// 1st iteration, y is 1:
int y = arc4random() % 2;
[self addChild:topObstacles[y]];

// 2nd iteration, y is randomly chosen to be 1 again:
int y = arc4random() % 2;
[self addChild:topObstacles[y]]; // BAM! This node has already been added...
```

To fix it, either pick another random number if `topObstacles[y].parent` is not nil or just remove the node you added from the array with `[topObstacles removeObjectAtIndex:y]` - this requires `topObstacles` to be an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I finally understand where I add the node twice. But if I want to add same node twice, what should I do? I want to generate random obstacles, sometimes the same obstacle can generate consecutively.

Comment: create a new sprite with the same texture/properties

Comment: @user3235456 - You should accept Cocos' answer if it solved your problem.